# How to redirect HTTPS traffic to a proxy on localhost:443?

Tags: c++, http, https, network-programming, mongoose-web-server

I'm building an HTTP server in C++ using the Cesanta Mongoose c++ networking library. Essentially I'm trying to redirect traffic from my web browser to a proxy on the localhost. I recently added support for HTTPS by purchasing a certificate and domain and following the instructions to enable ssl with mongoose (https://cesanta.com/docs/http/ssl.html). The server is now listening on port 443, and it runs fine. I've configured my web browser to direct HTTPS requests to localhost:443, but it doesn't appear to be triggering the HTTP server. When my server is listening on port 8080 and the web browser is configured to send requests to localhost:8080, it triggers the web browser, but it doesn't support https. Is there something wrong with configuring the web browser to send requests to localhost:443?

Comment: Would using something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) be possible in your situation? It offers secure tunneling to localhost over the internet and supports https as well.

Comment: @mrstack999 seems like it might be just what I need, I'll give it a go. Thx

Comment: No problem. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

ngrok solution is quite nice.

If you want to add a redirect in your application directly, set two listening connections: one HTTP, one HTTPS.

Use different event handler functions for those two listening connection: the HTTP handler would only send redirects, whereas HTTPS handler would do a real job:

```c
static void f1(struct mg_connection *c, int ev, void *ev_data, void *fn_data) {
  if (ev == MG_EV_HTTP_MSG) {
    struct mg_http_message *hm = (struct mg_http_message *) ev_data;
    struct mg_str *host = mg_http_get_header(hm, "Host");
    if (host == NULL) {
      mg_printf(c, "HTTP/1.1 500 Failed\r\n\r\n");
    } else {
      mg_printf(c, "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved\r\n"
                   "Location: https://%.*s%.*s\r\n\r\n",
                   (int) host->len, host->ptr,);
                   (int) hm->uri.len, hm->uri.ptr);  // Send redirect to HTTPS!
    }
    c->is_draining = 1;
  }
}

...
  mg_http_listen(&mgr, "http://0.0.0.0:80", f1, NULL);    // HTTP
  mg_http_listen(&mgr, "https://0.0.0.0:443", f2, NULL);  // HTTPS
```